# Write a Jquery inside the <?php?> tag

Tags: php, jquery

I want to write Jquery code inside `PHP` tag. I wanted to do this so that I can perform `AJAX` after that.

I have tried to echo it, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
    require("conn.php");
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from food order by LENGTH(price), price");
    if($rs!=false && mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
        $counter ++;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

            echo '
                    <script src="jquery.js">
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#'.$row["code"].'").click(function(){
                                echo "clicked";
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
            ';
        }
        mysql_free_result($rs);
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: So what does this produce in browser source code? Not nearly enough information shown

Comment: Your appoarch seems to be correct. But; "...it doesn't work." is just not a way to debug code. Find out what doesn't work, then why.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: If possible I'd give those clickable elements a common class e.g. <button class="code" ... /> and then using a selector e.g. $('button.code') to avoid referencing them by ID dynamically.

Comment: The code coloration is giving you the answer ... Look at the content of the ``echo`` and you'll see that you use ' character, you should escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small rearrangement of your code.

```
<?php
    require("conn.php");
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from food order by LENGTH(price), price");
    if($rs!=false && mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
        $counter ++;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

            echo '<a class="row_food">'. $row["code"] .'</a>';
        }
        mysql_free_result($rs);
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    mysql_close();
?>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.row_food').click(function(){
            alert("clicked");

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

You don't have to echo the javascript code every time in the loop! You only need to echo the content from your db inside the loop.

In the javascript/jquery, you could bind the click event to the element and do whatever you needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `</script>` after `jquery.js`.